# Wait for Simulink model execution

Tags: matlab, simulink

I wrote a script file in MATLAB that executes two functions as shown below:

```
function TempFunction()

fcn1();

fcn2();

end
```

After `fcn1()` is executed, I want the program to wait for execution of a model in Simulink, and then execute `fcn2()`.
How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want `fcn2()` and the simulink model to be running at the same time, or do you want `fcn2` to run after the simulink model has finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use a [Model Callback](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/model-callbacks.html) - set up a `'StopFcn'` to trigger the next thing you want to run.

Alternatively, you could go into a loop polling the `'SimulationStatus'` - see [this page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/using-the-sim-command.html#mw_1a507c46-af59-454b-a409-afa3fde8994f) in the doc. .

Answer (score 1):

you can call simulink models as functions from MATLAB as `sim('Model_Name')`

Read more about the options in the docs: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/using-the-sim-command.html

and the `sim` function: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/sim.html

Comment: No, my friend. I do not want to run simulation programmatically. I want to fnc2() wait until I run the model in Simulink by clicking on Run icon

Comment: Well @IdinEsmkhani you can do that by calling the function programatically just before `fnc2()`. Othewise, if you are going to be clicking on things, you can click on running `fnc2()` after clicking on running the simulink simulations.